# how to change a java code so that it will be customized by its subclasses with minimal impact

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring, code-reuse

My code has below situation.

```
class A{

    public void putLogicHere(){

        //method is about 500 lines long.

        //Initial Few lines of code will be common 

        //middle part of code will be customized by its subclasses

        //Again here comes few lines of common code

    }
}

class B extends A{}
class C extends A{}
```

At a design level what approach should I decide to break this code further? considering middle part of method will be customizd by others in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 5):

I would make class A an `abstract` class and create an abstract method in it like:

```
abstract void doAdditionalStuff(/*needed parameters from class A*/);
```

And use it in A like:

```
public void putLogicHere(){
    //Initial Few lines of code will be common 
    //Here use the abstract method implemented in subclasses
    doAdditionalStuff();

    //Again here comes few lines of common code

}
```

Class B and C could then implement that method:

```
@Override
doAdditionalStuff() {
  //middle part of code will be customized by its subclasses
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a question here - in the design you have mentioned , how do we write junits as superclass being abstract?

Comment: @VRK Just create a subclass in your test sources or use a mocking framework. E.g. with mockito you can create a mock of the abstract class and tell mockito to call the real method. But I think this is another question you should ask.

Comment: Thanks @RenéLink !

Answer (score 0):

Have a concept of the business logic as

- provided **service**(s)
- **requirements** (to produce something) resp. **callbacks** (to react) to be provided (implemented)

So:

```
(abstract) class Base {
    public final void oneService() {
        ...
        U u = requirementX(X x);
        ...
        V v = requirementY(Y y);
        ...
    }
    protected U requirementX(X x) {
    }
    abstract protected V requirementY(Y y);
}

class Aaa extends Base { ... }
class Bbb extends Base { ... }
```

Notice:

- A *service* may be final
- A *requirement* could be protected, should be overwritten, and can have extra contextual parameters prepared by the base class.

With Java 8 instead of inheritance for protected methods, setting some function pointers / lambda parameters might sometimes be nicer.